# Deep copying or cloning in actionscript 3

Tags: software-engineering, flash

I would like to make a mirror reflection of an entity in Flashpunk. So I would like to copy a spritemap from one Entity to another (`reflectionEntity`). If i use something like this

```
reflectionEntity.sprite = otherEntity.sprite;

reflectionEntity.sprite.scaleY=-1; // to reflect
```

then the graphic of the original entity is also scaled.

Is there a simple way out of this? I have been searching for the solution for more than an hour and have not found a suitable one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `reflectionEntity.sprite` is an instance of `Image` or `TiledSpriteMap`. In the [constructor for Image](https://github.com/ChevyRay/FlashPunk/blob/master/net/flashpunk/graphics/Image.as#L63) there's a `souce:*` parameter where you specify where the image comes from. This is the data you want to share.

Copying `reflectionEntity.sprite` (again, assuming that this is something like `Image`, or any subclass of `Graphic` really) just copies the references to that, which is why your changes propagate.

Flashpunk keeps an internal reference to the source, [as seen here](https://github.com/ChevyRay/FlashPunk/blob/master/net/flashpunk/graphics/Image.as#L290), but has it marked `protected` for whatever weird reason.

Keep the reference to whatever object you use to load your image, and pass that into a new instance like so:

```
[however the embed statement is written goes here, I forget]
var yourSpriteSource:Class; // Class, assuming you're doing resource embedding
/*
...
*/
otherEntity.sprite = new Image(yourSpriteSource);
reflectionEntity.sprite = new Image(yourSpriteSource);
```

Another alternative is to subclass each Graphic class you're interested in and expose the `source()` function. Another alternative to that (which is likely what *I* would do on a project), is fork Flashpunk and make the `source()` function public. But that's a bit extreme.

Think of `Graphic` subclasses as bits of data that know how to render the *real* graphics data, which is the `source` parameter you pass into their constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, probably this is how I am going to do this, I was looking for a simpler (and more elegant) solution, but I guess I will copy the source image and manually set the frames.

Comment: @James If you want to make it more elegant, extend Image/TiledSpriteMap/whatever you're using and write a clone() method for it that also sets the frames for the new clone.